# How do I get data from Flask? "Property assignment expected" keeps haunting me

Tags: javascript, flask

I just can't do it, I just can't get the simplest of lists into my script

I even copy pasted some code from another thread and still, Property. assignment. expected.

this is in my html file:

```
var getEmails = {{ emails|tojson|safe }}; //"Property assignment expected" error message
```

and this is where I send it from my Flask file:

```
@app.route('/example')
def example():
    emails = ['email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com']
    return render_template('example.html', emails=emails)
```

Comment: Why are you doing ```tojson```? Your ```emails``` is just an Array not a JSON object or an object with properties. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I don't even know... I just want to get and use my data, the actual app will have a bunch of coordinates and a for loop to add them to a leaflet map, but I just don't know how to get that data from Flask to my HTML file

Comment: nvm, `JSON.parse('{{ stops|tojson|safe }}');` just worked.